# Starting tasks again

Tags: ada, multitasking

I recently started Ada programming and now I'm stuck.
I created a program with multiple tasks. The main-task is managing incoming communication and as a consequence starts working-tasks or transfers data to the working-tasks.
The working-tasks are all of the same kind but with different identifiers. 
They do their work and should finish after that.  For example:

```ada
    task body Access_Protected is
    begin
     accept Start(foo: in Integer; foo2: out Integer)
       do something
     end Start;
    while Go_loop loop
     select 
       accept Quit do
         Go_loop := false;
       end Quit;
     or 
       accept Insert(foo3: in Integer)
        do something
        if something = 0 then
         Go_loop := false;
        end if;
       end Insert;
     or delay 2.0;
    end select;
    end loop;
    end Access_Protected;
```

I understand that the working-task should be terminated when the Go_loop is finished. Am I right?
It works to start the task one time but when the main-task tries to restart the working-task by calling the Start procedure, nothing happens.
Can someone please tell me which point I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

A `task` and subprogram are somewhat related in that when the body is completed the construct ends, this is to say that the construct ends with it's appropriate `end`; in the case of a `procedure` control returns to the caller, in the case of a `function` the exception `PROGRAM_ERROR` is raised, and in the case of a `task` the controlling "thread" terminates.

What's happening in your particular problem, it seems, boils down to the following:

```
Package Example is
    Task Type Message_Task is
        Entry Execute;
    End Message_Task;
End Example;

Package Body Example is
    Task Body Message_Task is
        Use Ada.Text_IO;
    Begin
        accept Execute  do
            Put_Line( "Rendezvous!" );
        end Execute;
        delay 0.2; -- Stub delay.
        Put_Line( "Finishing Task." );
        -- Task Ends Here.
    End Message_Task;
End Example;

--...
Test : Example.Message_Task;
--...

Test.Execute;
-- Test.Execute can't be accepted here because it can only accept "Execute"
-- the one time, as per the body's definition.
```

The reason that this **really is** like your problem is because, likewise once you say "`X.Start(1,2)`" another call to `Start` *doesn't* reset the position of the task's execution back up to that accept.

If you wanted the task to "stay alive" for further processing you could do one of two options.

Option 1 -- set up a 'protocol':

```
Package Example is
    Task Type Message_Task is
        Entry Initialization;
        Entry Execute;
        Entry Quit;
    End Message_Task;
End Example;

Package Body Example is
    Task Body Message_Task is
        Use Ada.Text_IO;
        Has_quit : Boolean := False;
    Begin
        Main:
        loop
            select
                accept Initialization  do
                    null;
                end Initialization;
                accept Execute  do
                    null;
                end Execute;
            or
                accept Quit do
                    Has_Quit := True;
                end Quit;
            end select;
            Exit Main when Has_Quit;
        end loop Main;
    End Message_Task;
End Example;
```

Option 2 -- Allow termination.

```
Package Example is
    Task Type Message_Task is
        Entry Initialization;
        Entry Execute;
    End Message_Task;
End Example;

Package Body Example is
    Task Body Message_Task is
        Use Ada.Text_IO;
        Has_quit : Boolean := False;
    Begin
        accept Initialization  do
            null;
        end Initialization;

        Main:
        loop
            select
                accept Execute  do
                    null;
                end Execute;
            or
                terminate;
            end select;
        end loop Main;
    End Message_Task;
End Example;
```

The subtle difference is Option 2 gets rid of the `Quit` entry, allowing the task to 'rest' on the `terminate` alternative while Option 1 is more explicit in control (and required in some cases), but requiring that `Initialization` & `Execute` be called in pairs.

Answer (score 2):

A task only runs until it reaches the end of its main sequence of statements (ignoring various technicalities).

If you want a task to do something, and then pause until it receives an external trigger, you should put a loop around the statements you have in the task body.

Comment: Is it not possible to restart the task, after the first execution? I don't want to waste cpu time with paused tasks. The task should do his work, finish and restart from the beginning after some time

Comment: No.  But you can have a task type, and create new tasks of that type as needed.  Waiting tasks don't use CPU, so my suggestion can hardly be said to waste CPU time.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help